Call fmt::streamed if needed
I have a wrapper on top of spdlog, and after upgrading the spdlog and fmt versions, I have a bunch of errors because some of my types doesn't provide a formatter. Instead of adding fmt::streamed where I call spdlog with my types, I am trying to add a template function that calls fmt::streamed if there isnt a formatter, and just returns the original value otherwise.
template <typename Arg>
int streamedIfNeeded(Arg &&arg) {

    if constexpr(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(fmt::format<fmt::format_string<Arg>, Arg&&>), decltype("{}"), Arg>) {
        return arg;
    } else {
        return fmt::streamed(arg);
    }
}

However, this is not working correctly. As shown in https://godbolt.org/z/dddsqv9x6 , it is always going through the false branch.
How should I fix this template so it works as expected?

You have provided very poor [mcve] (it is not clear what is the purpose of streamedIfNeeded and why you are including Eigen library). Anyway it works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/MedM8sEzE (maybe I misunderstand your problem).

I've read your question couple times and try understand why you are doing this strange things and I'm pretty sure your question suffers form XY problem. Looks like you come up with some strange solution to some simple problem and asking to fix your strange solution. Here is a fix to your solution: https://godbolt.org/z/vr6Tqqrax

You can use fmt::is_formattable for this:
template <typename Arg>
int streamedIfNeeded(Arg&& arg) {
  if constexpr(fmt::is_formattable<Arg>()) {
    return arg;
  } else {
    return fmt::streamed(arg);
  }
}


You also may want to use auto instead of int as the return type of this method.

Doesn't fmt::is_formattable fail for certain conversions or types? I remember reading something like that in fmt github

No, it should work correctly for any formattable type.
